# I ge a "port 22: Connection refused" error on ssh?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have ipv6 address, and I tried like `ssh user@ipv6`. I am getting a

`port 22: Connection refused`
error while connecting to a server.

I have both the openssh client and server installed, and they are running. But still there is an error. I get,

```
$ sudo netstat -anp | grep sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1538/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1538/sshd       
unix   3   [] STREAM      CONNECTED    23333     20222/sshd
```

But  `sudo iptables -L | grep ssh` returns nothing also I dont install ufw.

PC is ubuntu desktop and I installed openssh server it and trying to access from another ubnuntu pc as client.

Comment: @guiverc I updated question

Comment: 20.04 ubuntu desktop

Comment: Actually I have two server pc with same ip address within  and one client with different ip outside lan